# Why does my vue app triggers an onload event in the parent iframe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, internet-explorer, iframe

I'm loading a vue app into an iframe. I have a simple script that creates the iframe and adds the vue bundle to it. This works flawlessly in Chrome, Safari and FF but repeatedly triggers an onload event on the iframe in IE Edge, causing my vue app to reload all the time.

I've tried setting a variable `isLoaded` after the first onload event to prevent further onLoads but this way the app doesn't render at all.

First the script creates the frame:

```
this.iframe = d.createElement("iframe");
this.iframe.id = "FrameID";
this.iframe.name = "FrameName";
```

Then I wait for the onLoad event to initialize the frame

```
this.iframe.addEventListener("load", function() {        
 self.initIframe(self.iframe);
});
```

Then in my init function

```
  self.initIframe = function(iframe) {
    var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
    var body = doc.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

    //Vue app mounting element 
    var root = doc.createElement("div");
    root.id = "vue-app";
    body.appendChild(root);

    //Add bundle to iframe
    var vueappbundle = doc.createElement("script");
    appjs.src = self.baseUrl + "js/vuebundle.js;
    body.appendChild(appjs);
}
```

As said, this works in Chrome, FF and Safari but the app keeps reloading in IE Edge. Adding the vue app url as src to the iframe does work but then I'm unable to communicate between iframe and parent website since my vue app runs on another domain.

Comment: Is there any error or warning message in the console of IE browser? For testing purpose, try to lower down the security settings of IE and make sure all the zones has similar security settings. Also try to enable the option called 'Access data sources across domains' in security settings. If possible for you than you can create a sample with JSFidle or codepen. so we can also try to test it using IE.

Comment: Are you asking about IE or Edge? They are two completely separate browsers.

Comment: Edge. It happens in both but I don't need to support IE.

Comment: Did you tried what I suggested you in my previous comment? Does it worked? If issue still persist than please try to provide a working sample using JSFiddle or Codepen. So that we can try to test the issue with IE and Edge browser. It can help to understand the issue in better way. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve by changing the Vue router mode to 'abstract'. Somehow the hash router seemed to trigger the load event multiple times.